# Running program on Windows compiled with C++ gives ZNKSt7 Error

Tags: c++, g++, mingw32

I have been writing some simple code that reads files, prints, writes to files and downloads files (via a external executable) To read the  files im using mINI which can be found [here](https://github.com/pulzed/mINI).

What I'm importing:

```
string
iostream
cctype
vector
stdio.h
memory
cstdio
stdexcept
sstream
"mini/ini.h"
memory
```

What I'm defining:

```
CURL_STATICLIB
```

I am using this command to compile my code to Windows x32-bit:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ -o main.exe main.cpp
```

After compiling and running it on my Windows Machine I get this error:
[image]

```
Der Prozedureinsprungpunkt "_ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEE12find_last_ofEcj" wurde in der DLL "J:\main.exe" nicht gefunden.
```

Translated with Google Translate:

```
The procedure entry point "_ZNKSt7__cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEE12find_last_ofEcj" was not found in the DLL "J:\main.exe".
```

Any help would be apprieciated!

Regards Alex

Comment: My guess is a dll conflict. Although it's odd to me that the executable is listed in the error dialog. I would expect it to mention a dll and in that case the problem is likely caused by having different versions of the MinGW runtime installed on your system with an incompatible one above the correct one in your PATH environment variable.